# GMSTileURLConstructor Returns Strange Data for Zoom

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to draw a custom overlay on Google Maps for iOS using `GMSTileURLConstructor`.

I am using the following code to get my URL

```
GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {
        NSString *url = @"";

        for (NSDictionary *limits in [selectedPropertyMap objectForKey:@"property_map_zoom_levels"]) {
            int zoomLevel = [[limits objectForKey:@"level"] intValue];
            int tileMinX = 0;
            int tileMaxX = 0;
            int tileMinY = 0;
            int tileMaxY = 0;

            if ([limits objectForKey:@"tile_min_x"] != (id)[NSNull null]) {
                tileMinX = [[limits objectForKey:@"tile_min_x"] intValue];
            }
            if ([limits objectForKey:@"tile_max_x"] != (id)[NSNull null]) {
                tileMaxX = [[limits objectForKey:@"tile_max_x"] intValue];
            }
            if ([limits objectForKey:@"tile_min_y"] != (id)[NSNull null]) {
                tileMinY = [[limits objectForKey:@"tile_min_y"] intValue];
            }
            if ([limits objectForKey:@"tile_max_y"] != (id)[NSNull null]) {
                tileMaxY = [[limits objectForKey:@"tile_max_y"] intValue];
            }

            if (zoomLevel == (unsigned long)zoom) {
                if ((tileMinX <= x) && (tileMaxX >= x) && (tileMinY <= y) && (tileMaxY >= y)) {
                    url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@/%@/%lu_%lu.png", MAP_URL, [property objectForKey:@"id"], [limits objectForKey:@"property_map_id"], [limits objectForKey:@"id"], (unsigned long)x, (unsigned long)y];
                    NSLog(@"url -> %@/zoom %lu/%i",url, (unsigned long)zoom, zoomLevel);
                    return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
                }
            }
        }
        return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    };
```

When I log out the URL, zoom and zoomLevel I get the following information:

`2014-05-16 17:25:15.621 Application[24491:61003] url -> <BASEURL>/16/9/19/159786_195303.png/zoom 19/19`

At the same time, I am logging the camera zoom when the camera changes

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {
    zoomLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ZL: %.2f",position.zoom];
    NSLog(@"camera changed - zoom %f",position.zoom);
    [self hideMarkersBasedOnZoom:position.zoom];
    if(position.zoom > 21) {
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:position.target.latitude longitude:position.target.longitude zoom:21];
        [mapView_ setCamera:camera];
    }
}
```

Which logs

`2014-05-16 17:25:15.640 Application[24491:60b] camera changed - zoom 18.022364`

Can anyone explain the discrepancy in zoom level value and how to have it match appropriately?

Comment: What version of Google Map SDK that you are using? 1.8.0 or 1.7.2?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @funkybro Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 7):

After I did some research, I believe the way Google handles the **zoom level** for `GMSTileLayer` is not the same with zoom level for the `camera of mapView`.

**GMSTileLayer Class Reference**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_tile_layer

> At zoom level 0 the whole world is a square covered by a single tile,
>   and the coordinates x and y are both 0 for that tile. At zoom level 1,
>   the world is covered by 4 tiles with x and y being 0 or 1, and so on.

**For the mapView Camera**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#zoom

> The zoom level of the camera determines the scale of the map. At
>   larger zoom levels more detail can be seen on the screen, while at
>   smaller zoom levels more of the world can be seen on the screen. At
>   zoom level 0, the scale of the map is such that the entire world has a
>   width of approximately 256 points.
>
> Increasing the zoom level by 1 doubles the width of the world on the
>   screen. Hence at zoom level N, the width of the world is approximately
>   256 * 2N, i.e., at zoom level 2, the whole world is approximately 1024
>   points wide. Note that the zoom level need not be an integer. The
>   range of zoom levels permitted by the map depends on a number of
>   factors including location, map type and screen size.

The zoom for `GMSTileLayer` is **NSUInteger** while the zoom for `camera` is **float**. The zoom for GMSTileLayer is used to determine the **number of tiles**. While the zoom for camera is used to determine the **number of points** based on the formula **256 * 2N**.

I could be wrong but I think both the zoom levels would not be matched up.

Not so related: Google just released iOS Maps SDK V1.8.1 that solved an issue related to GMSTileLayer and also fixed a crash.