# iOS Google map SDK: Setting maxZoom level issue when using Tiles

Tags: ios, google-maps

I notice when I set the max Zoom level of example to 19, the zoom go up to 20 when I'm using tiles. I don't know why. It's always 1 more zoom level than the one I set.

See below example (This from Google SDKDemo Example, I just changed URL to point to my domain):

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:23.614328
                                                          longitude:58.545284
                                                               zoom:18];

  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

   [mapView_ setMinZoom:5 maxZoom:19];
  //mapView_.buildingsEnabled = NO;
  //mapView_.indoorEnabled = NO;
    mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
  self.view = mapView_;

 tileLayer_.map = nil;

    // Create a new GMSTileLayer with the new floor choice.
    GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {
      NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/%tu/%tu/%tu.png",  zoom, x, y];
       NSLog(@"URL: %@",url);
      return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    };
    tileLayer_ = [GMSURLTileLayer tileLayerWithURLConstructor:urls];
    tileLayer_.map = mapView_;
```

Now, if I kept zoom in. I will get the log printed:

2014-12-22 20:06:02.342 SDKDemos[1792:941894] URL: http://www.example.com/20/694778/453520.png

Notice, the zoom level after the domain is 20 although, the max I set it to 19.
Notice, I'm using Google SDK version 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the zoom in GMSTileURLConstructor is different from the zoom in MapView.

I tried to put the some NSLog inside the GMSTileURLConstructor block, like the following:

```
GMSTileURLConstructor urls = ^(NSUInteger x, NSUInteger y, NSUInteger zoom) {
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/%tu/%tu/%tu.png",  zoom, x, y];
        NSLog(@"URL: %@",url);
        NSLog(@"max zoom: %f", mapView_.maxZoom);
        NSLog(@"max tileLayer zoom: %f", tileLayer_.map.maxZoom);
        return [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    };
```

It prints

```
2014-12-22 08:56:07.959 HelloMap[30797:1797670] max zoom: 19.000000
2014-12-22 08:56:07.959 HelloMap[30797:1797670] max tileLayer zoom: 19.000000
```

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23841108/4195406) might help you.

Part from the answer:

*"The zoom for GMSTileLayer is NSUInteger while the zoom for camera is float. The zoom for GMSTileLayer is used to determine the number of tiles. While the zoom for camera is used to determine the number of points based on the formula 256 * 2N."*